# Why could a UPS device need of a microprocessor?

Tags: ups

I have read about some **UPS** devices that are **microprocessor-controlled**, and I would like to understand the **fundamentals of needing** such a microelectronical device like a CPU for what it just seem a current management machine.

- **Why** do some (all?) UPS devices incorporate a microprocessor? What do my UPS loose **if it has not** one inside?
- How complex/advanced is this microprocessor and what are the **advantages** of having a better microprocessor for a UPS?
- What happens if this microprocessor is **not good** enough, and how may **detect such flaw**?

Comment: Typically a UPS has some way to telling the outside it's status via serial, USB or ethernet. For the power part you can get away without one I think. But I've never designed a UPS...

Comment: Why put a CPU in a hifi?

Comment: You could look at some reference design, e.g. [Single Phase On-Line UPS Using MC9S12E128](http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/DRM064.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

There are many advantages.  First, an MCU can replace quite a bit of discrete logic and monitoring circuitry for less than the cost of discrete parts or an ASIC.  UPS units need to monitor several different parameters (line voltage, battery charge, load current, etc).  Many MCUs have built-in ADCs, so using a microcontroller means that most of the necessary logic can be implemented in software on the MCU instead of discrete components.  This logic would include things like undervoltage and overvoltage monitoring, battery level monitoring, hysteresis, timeouts, etc.  In general, the MCU will replace a number of discrete logic chips and simplify the control circuitry.  It also becomes trivial to add external status reporting over a serial port or even over Ethernet.  Using an MCU also allows the UPS to be remotely managed - thresholds and timeouts adjusted, output enabled/disabled, etc.

Microcontrollers capable of this would be rather simple.  The atmega328p used in the popular Arduino boards is pretty representative of what you might find in a UPS - 8 bit processor, a few KB of SRAM, a few KB of flash, clock of a few MHz, ADC of a few ksa/sec.  For one that supports Ethernet, it would probably use an ARM-based MCU of some sort, or at least something 32-bit, to deal with the network interface.  Possibly even two MCUs, one for interfacing and one for control and monitoring.

Personally, I would be more surprised to see a UPS that *didn't* use a microcontroller of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

> - Why do some (all?) UPS devices incorporate a microprocessor? What do    my UPS loose if it has not one inside?

The microcontroller inside provides an easy way to **control** the UPS, including reporting status information, managing charging, responding to events, etc. You lose a lot of flexibility without one.

> - How complex/advanced is this microprocessor and what are the advantages of having a better microprocessor for a UPS?

**It depends** on the UPS. Most likely, it exactly as advanced as the lowest cost option capable of performing the specified needs. If you have more needs, then you may need a more advanced device.

> - What happens if this microprocessor is not good enough, and how may    detect such flaw?

**If it's not good enough then it's not used in the UPS**. The UPS is an engineered product, they don't use parts that can't perform the tasks required. You're not going to detect this perceived flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself: what does a microcontroller do ? What would it add to a UPS ?

If you just want a box that powers a load from a battery when the mains voltage is interrupted, you could build that without a microcontroller. For the basic UPS functionality, a microcontroller is NOT NEEDED.

But if you do incorporate a microcontroller you can more easily add extra functionality like monitoring from a PC. An indicator that tells you to test the battery every 6 months. A beep when the UPS kicks in. You could also implement that without a micro controller but it would be more easy and flexible with it. And since microcontrollers are so cheap nowadays almost any device has one.